# Hibernate and Karaf java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am working on a project using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final and karaf 4.0.2. When loading the hibernate config I get the following exception, However the class that fails loading is in the bundle. I Hope somebody can help me with this problem. I have been trying to fix it for several days and I am running out of ideas.

Thanks

```
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: Service factory exception: Unable to load class [ com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.GroupRoleRoleItem] declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry
at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getFactoryUnchecked(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:352)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:247)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:343)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.getService(Felix.java:3692)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:470)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at com.asm.infraMngr.database.sessionFactory.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:39)[119:com.asm.infraMngr.database:0.0.1]
at com.asm.infraMngr.database.sessionFactory.HibernateUtil.getSession(HibernateUtil.java:29)[119:com.asm.infraMngr.database:0.0.1]
at com.asm.infraMngr.database.security.daoImpl.UsersDaoImpl.addUser(UsersDaoImpl.java:64)[119:com.asm.infraMngr.database:0.0.1]
at com.asm.infraMngr.AppTesting.activator.Activator.start(Activator.java:50)[122:com.asm.infraMngr.AppTesting:0.0.1]
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2220)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2138)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:964)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Install.execute(Install.java:96)[23:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.2]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.action.command.ActionCommand.execute(ActionCommand.java:83)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:67)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:87)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.run(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:268)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.GroupRoleRoleItem] declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2281)[97:org.hibernate.core:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2229)[97:org.hibernate.core:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2209)[97:org.hibernate.core:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2162)[97:org.hibernate.core:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2077)[97:org.hibernate.core:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiSessionFactoryService.getService(OsgiSessionFactoryService.java:102)[100:org.hibernate.osgi:4.3.11.Final]
at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getFactoryUnchecked(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:347)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.GroupRoleRoleItem not found by org.hibernate.core [97]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1558)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1998)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)[:1.8.0_40]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:193)[97:org.hibernate.core:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2278)[97:org.hibernate.core:4.3.11.Final]
```

Below my hibernate config

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:ASM_DB;create=true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.Users" />
<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.Group" />
<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.GroupRole" />
<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.GroupRoleRoleItem" />
<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.ItService" />
<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.HttpInfo" />
<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.JmxInfo" />
<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.ServerInfo" />
<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.SshInfo" />
<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.UserAttempts" />
<mapping class="com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity.ServiceAudit" />
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

#

I am loading the hibernate session with the following class

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;


public class HibernateUtil {

private SessionFactory sf;

public Session getSession() {
return getSessionFactory().openSession();
}

private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
if ( sf == null ) {
Bundle thisBundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle( HibernateUtil.class );
// Could get this by wiring up OsgiTestBundleActivator as well.
BundleContext context = thisBundle.getBundleContext();

ServiceReference sr = context.getServiceReference( SessionFactory.class.getName() );
sf = (SessionFactory) context.getService( sr );
}
return sf;
}
}
```

The POM dependencies are the following

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<hibernate.core.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.core.version>
<bundle.symbolicName>com.asm.infraMngr.database</bundle.symbolicName>
<bundle.namespace>com.asm.infraMngr.database</bundle.namespace>

</properties>

<build>

<plugins>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.0</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<!--
the following instructions build a simple set of public/private classes into an OSGi bundle
-->
<configuration>
<manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
<instructions>
<Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
<Bundle-Version>${pom.version}</Bundle-Version>
<Bundle-Activator>com.asm.infraMngr.database.activator.ActivatorDBModule</Bundle-Activator>
<Spring-Context>*;publish-context:=false;create-asynchronously:=true</Spring-Context>
<Bundle-ClassPath>.,./config/</Bundle-ClassPath>
<DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
<Bundle-ManifestVersion>2</Bundle-ManifestVersion>
<Bundle-ActivationPolicy>lazy</Bundle-ActivationPolicy>
<Export-Package>
com.asm.infraMngr.database.services.dao,
com.asm.infraMngr.database.security.dao,
com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity
</Export-Package>
<Import-Package>
org.hibernate;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.cfg;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.service;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.proxy;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.mapping;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.annotations;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.envers.*;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.hibernate.boot.registry;version=${hibernate.core.version},
org.osgi.framework;version=1.0,
org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang;version=0,
org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.locator;version=0,
org.apache.log4j;version=1.2.15,
org.apache.derby.jdbc;version=10.12.1.1,
javax.xml.datatype;version=0.0.0
</Import-Package>
</instructions>
</configuration>
</plugin>

</plugins>

</build>


<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
<artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>xerces</groupId>
<artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>c3p0</groupId>
<artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
<version>0.9.1.2</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
<artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.derby</artifactId>
<version>10.12.1.1_1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
<artifactId>hyperjaxb3-ejb-runtime</artifactId>
<version>0.5.6</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
<artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
<version>0.4.1.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
<artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0</version>
<!--scope>provided</scope-->
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The class that is not loading is as follows

```
package com.asm.infraMngr.database.entity;


import com.asm.infraMngr.database.enums.RoleEnum;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SelectBeforeUpdate;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditTable;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.item.Item;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity(name = "GroupRoleRoleItem")
@Table(name = "GROUP_ROLE_ROLE_ITEM")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DynamicUpdate(true)
@SelectBeforeUpdate(true)
@Audited
@AuditTable("GROUP_ROLE_ROLE_ITEM_AUD")
public class GroupRoleRoleItem
        implements Item<RoleEnum>
{

    @XmlElement(name = "Role")
    protected RoleEnum item;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Hjid")
    protected Long hjid;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the item property.
     *
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link RoleEnum }
     *
     */
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ITEM", length = 50)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public RoleEnum getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the item property.
     *
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link RoleEnum }
     *
     */
    public void setItem(RoleEnum value) {
        this.item = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the hjid property.
     *
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Long }
     *
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "HJID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getHjid() {
        return hjid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the hjid property.
     *
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Long }
     *
     */
    public void setHjid(Long value) {
        this.hjid = value;
    }

}
```

After further troubleshooting I got a comment from another post to include  org.hibernate.internal.util on the Import-Package tag. After this the original problem was solved. now I have a new exception. Then exception states the hibernate.cfg.xml file is not found, however the file is in the location written in the exception which is "/config/hibernate.cfg.xml"

```
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: Service factory exception: /config/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getFactoryUnchecked(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:352)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:247)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:343)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.getService(Felix.java:3692)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:470)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
    at com.asm.infraMngr.database.sessionFactory.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:39)[135:com.asm.infraMngr.database:0.0.1]
    at com.asm.infraMngr.database.sessionFactory.HibernateUtil.getSession(HibernateUtil.java:29)[135:com.asm.infraMngr.database:0.0.1]
    at com.asm.infraMngr.database.security.daoImpl.UsersDaoImpl.addUser(UsersDaoImpl.java:64)[135:com.asm.infraMngr.database:0.0.1]
    at com.asm.infraMngr.AppTesting.activator.Activator.start(Activator.java:50)[136:com.asm.infraMngr.AppTesting:0.0.1]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2220)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2138)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:964)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.2.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Install.execute(Install.java:96)[23:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.action.command.ActionCommand.execute(ActionCommand.java:83)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:67)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:87)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.run(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:268)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /config/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)[97:org.hibernate.core:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2095)[97:org.hibernate.core:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2076)[97:org.hibernate.core:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiSessionFactoryService.getService(OsgiSessionFactoryService.java:102)[100:org.hibernate.osgi:4.3.11.Final]
```

Comment: After further troubleshooting I got a comment from another post to include  org.hibernate.internal.util on the Import-Package tag. After this the original problem was solved. now I have a new exception

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, form some reason Karaf keeps references on an old  hibernate bundle even after uninstalling the bundle, so the hibernate config file was not found by karaf.  To solve the problem I  deleted the "data" directory in karaf to restart fresh. Then I installed all the dependencies and  finally my bundle. Then  the hibernate config file was found  on the bundle started up correctly.